# ng-switch for a particular row in a ng-repeat table

Tags: angularjs

I need to implement switching of buttons. Here I am getting data from a json file to populate the table using ng-repeat. Now when I click the 'Edit' button, all the edit buttons in the table are getting switched to 'Save' buttons. I want only that particular button to get switched. So please help in this issue.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="host in hosts|filter:search:strict" ng-switch on="editSave">
    <td>{{host.hostCd}}</td>
    <td>{{host.hostName}}</td>
    <td>
      <span ng-switch-when="false"><button style="width:50px;" class="btn btn-mini btn-warning" data-ng-click="edit()"><b>Edit</b></button></span>
      <span ng-switch-when="true"><button style="width:50px;" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" data-ng-click="save()"><b>Save</b></button></span>

      <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger deleteRow"><b>Delete</b></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Script**

```
$scope.editSave = false;
$scope.edit = function() {
    $scope.editSave = true;
};
$scope.save = function() {
    $scope.editSave = false;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="host in hosts|filter:search:strict" ng-init="host.editSave = false">
    <td>{{host.hostCd}}</td>
    <td>{{host.hostName}}</td>
    <td>
      <span ng-hide="host.editSave"><button style="width:50px;" class="btn btn-mini btn-warning" data-ng-click="edit(host)"><b>Edit</b></button></span>
      <span ng-show="host.editSave"><button style="width:50px;" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" data-ng-click="save(host)"><b>Save</b></button></span>

      <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger deleteRow"><b>Delete</b></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Script**

```
$scope.edit = function(host) {
   host.editSave = true;
};
$scope.save = function(host) {
   host.editSave = false;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative 1:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="host in hosts|filter:search:strict" ng-init="edit = true">
    <td>{{host.hostCd}}</td>
    <td>{{host.hostName}}</td>
    <td>
      <span ng-show="edit"><button style="width:50px;" class="btn btn-mini btn-warning" data-ng-click="edit = !edit"><b>Edit</b></button></span>
      <span ng-hide="edit"><button style="width:50px;" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" data-ng-click="edit = !edit"><b>Save</b></button></span>

      <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger deleteRow"><b>Delete</b></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```